# JavaScript change the color of current element by clck

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a question about changing the color of only Current element. 
So i want to change the background color of the current element by every click.

My problem is, i can not reset the background color of previous element.

For an example i have here  two background color(yellow, lightblue), if i click on "old div" and "new div", than the  background color of two divs changes to green. But only one div should be set to green.

So by every click must change only the background color of current element.

JavaScript

```
var divTag = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divTag.length; i++) {
    if (divTag[i].tagName == "DIV" || divTag[i].tagName == "div") {
         if (divTag[i].addEventListener) {
            divTag[i].addEventListener('click', callback,false);
         } 
         else if (divTag[i].attachEvent) {
            divTag[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click',callback);
         }
    }
}

function callback(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="old">
    <input style="margin: 10px;" type="textbox" />
    <div id="new"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#old {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#new{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you worried about performance, you can just save previous  and reset it's background color to normal.

```
var prevDiv = null;

function callback(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(prevDiv) {
        prevDiv.style.backgroundColor = '';        
    }
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    prevDiv = target;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/

Answer (score 1):

Reset the background colour of all other divs when you click one.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4uosvc75/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have a lot of div in my webpage, if i reset all the background color of divs, it can reduce the performace or i think wrong?