# How can I change an image of a button while clicked on in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript and want to design 5 buttons for moving forward, backward, left, right and stop.
I have done it successfully, but I want to change the button image when clicked.
I tried using some function like `clickon()` and give the button an `id`, but always saw this message:

> JavaScript : missing semicolon.

All the images of the buttons I have imported from my computer along with other images needed for the change.

Could you please advise me on how to apply the image change for one button, say for the forward one? Then I can adapt it to others too.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> UI buttons for controlling the robot </title>
        
        <style>
            div {
                
                margin: 250px 700px; <!-- to have the buttons in the middle -->
            }
            
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
       <div>
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
           
         <form>
             <td> 
            <input name="Forward" type = "image" src= "Forward.png" alt="Forward" hegiht="100" width="150" >
            </td>
             
         </form>
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form>
            <td>
                 <input Name="Left" type = "image" src= "Left.png" alt="Left" hegiht="100" width="150"
            </td>
           <td>
            
               <input Name="Stop" type = "image" src= "Stop.png" alt="STOP!" hegiht="100" width="150" >
               
           </td>
           <td>
                 <input Name="Right" type = "image" src= "Right.png" alt="Right" hegiht="100" width="150"
            </td>
           
             
            </form>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <form>
            <td>
                  <input Name="Backwards" type = "image" src= "Backward.png" alt="backwards!" hegiht="100" width="150" >
            </td>
             </form>
        </tr>
                     
       </table>
            </div>
            
    </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript change the color of current element by clck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044956/javascript-change-the-color-of-current-element-by-clck)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried in javascript that is throwing that error?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken only input with `name` "Forward" and try to change the image using JavaScript by altering the `src` and `alt` attributes on click. In this, `src` attribute got updated with *"MovingForwad.png"* image and `alt` attribute text updated with *"MovingForwad"*. Similarly, we can for other images too.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="Forward"]').addEventListener('click', changeImage);

function changeImage() {
  document.querySelector('[name="Forward"]').setAttribute('src', 'MovingForward.png');
  document.querySelector('[name="Forward"]').setAttribute('alt', 'Moving Forward');
}
```

```html
<input name="Forward" type="image" src="Forward.png" alt="Forward" hegiht="100" width="150">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css button:active{backgroun-image:url();} property